# ¿Por qué si en C# invoco un script con PowerShell y capturo el búfer es completamente diferente al ejecutarlo desde la terminal de Windows?

Tags: c#, powershell, .net8.0

¿Por qué si en C# invoco un script con PowerShell y capturo el búfer es completamente diferente al ejecutarlo desde la terminal de Windows?

Se supone que estoy invocando la misma aplicación  para ejecutar el comando (PowerShell) desde C# ... tal cual que se ejecuta en Windows Terminal PS.

Ejecuto esto en una aplicación C# abierta con privilegios elevados:

```
string command = "docker-compose -p wsdd-projects -f C:\Docker-Structure\init.yml up -d --build"

string policy = "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force";

string arguments = $"-NoProfile -Command \"{policy} ; '{command}'\"";

ProcessStartInfo processBuilder = new("powershell")
{
    Arguments = arguments,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    Verb = "runas",
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
};
```

capturamos la salida con:

```
Process process = new() { StartInfo = processBuilder };

process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
    {
        if (showOutput) { terminal.AddToTerminal(e.Data); }
        output.AppendLine(e.Data);
    }
};

process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
    {
        if (showOutput) { terminal.AddToTerminal(e.Data); }
        output.AppendLine(e.Data);
    }
};

process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();

await process.WaitForExitAsync();
```

Obtengo este resultado de la invocación de PS desde C#:

```
 reverse-proxy Pulled
 phpmyadmin Pulled
 faef57eae888 Pull complete
 989a1d6c052e Pull complete
 0705c9c2f22d Pull complete
 621478e043ce Pull complete
 98246dcca987 Pull complete
 bfed8c155cb6 Pull complete
 7a7c2e908867 Pull complete
 d176994b625c Pull complete
 2d8ace6a2716 Pull complete
 c70df516383c Pull complete
 15e1b44fe4c7 Pull complete
 65e50d44e95a Pull complete
 77f68910bc0a Pull complete
 605dd3a6e332 Pull complete
 99ce27188f07 Pull complete
 74d64e32c5d5 Pull complete
 ef5fc9928b9f Pull complete
 163f3256e112 Pull complete
 8a1e25ce7c4f Pull complete
 e78b137be355 Pull complete
 39fc875bd2b2 Pull complete
 035788421403 Pull complete
 87c3fb37cbf2 Pull complete
 c5cdd1ce752d Pull complete
 33952c599532 Pull complete
 80bad5b02d6c Pull complete
 b86cede81497 Pull complete
 876ba35ce95b Pull complete
 ac8fec215cc8 Pull complete
 7795496aa545 Pull complete
 4f4fb700ef54 Pull complete
```

En lugar de esta salida en Terminal PS Windows:

```
[+] Running 33/33
 ✔ reverse-proxy 13 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled                   14.3s
   ✔ 8a1e25ce7c4f Pull complete                                                      8.1s
   ✔ e78b137be355 Pull complete                                                      8.5s
   ✔ 39fc875bd2b2 Pull complete                                                      6.9s
   ✔ 035788421403 Pull complete                                                      7.6s
   ✔ 87c3fb37cbf2 Pull complete                                                      8.1s
   ✔ c5cdd1ce752d Pull complete                                                      8.6s
   ✔ 33952c599532 Pull complete                                                      8.7s
   ✔ 80bad5b02d6c Pull complete                                                      9.0s
   ✔ b86cede81497 Pull complete                                                      9.4s
   ✔ 876ba35ce95b Pull complete                                                      9.8s
   ✔ ac8fec215cc8 Pull complete                                                      9.6s
   ✔ 7795496aa545 Pull complete                                                      10.1s
   ✔ 4f4fb700ef54 Pull complete                                                      10.2s
 ✔ phpmyadmin 18 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled                  18.4s
   ✔ faef57eae888 Pull complete                                                      2.3s
   ✔ 989a1d6c052e Pull complete                                                      0.5s
   ✔ 0705c9c2f22d Pull complete                                                      4.7s
   ✔ 621478e043ce Pull complete                                                      1.0s
   ✔ 98246dcca987 Pull complete                                                      3.0s
   ✔ bfed8c155cb6 Pull complete                                                      2.8s
   ✔ 7a7c2e908867 Pull complete                                                      3.5s
   ✔ d176994b625c Pull complete                                                      4.3s
   ✔ 2d8ace6a2716 Pull complete                                                      4.1s
   ✔ c70df516383c Pull complete                                                      5.1s
   ✔ 15e1b44fe4c7 Pull complete                                                      4.8s
   ✔ 65e50d44e95a Pull complete                                                      5.3s
   ✔ 77f68910bc0a Pull complete                                                      5.4s
   ✔ 605dd3a6e332 Pull complete                                                      5.9s
   ✔ 99ce27188f07 Pull complete                                                      6.1s
   ✔ 74d64e32c5d5 Pull complete                                                      6.5s
   ✔ ef5fc9928b9f Pull complete                                                      6.4s
```

donde esta la linea:
`[+] Running`

Y las caracteres:
`✔`, `[⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]`

Comment: entiendo lo del utf-8, pero los caracteres [+] son simples caracteres...

Comment: estoy casi seguro de que docker tiene algun tipo de output distinto a "OutputDataReceived" y "ErrorDataReceived" pero no logro encontrar nada relacionado.